# ¿Cómo llamo los parametros pedidos por info_fields omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Debo pedir parametros adicionales a los que me entrega omniauth por lo cual hice esto:

```
provider :facebook, 'key',   'key',{:info_fields =>'name,email,first_name,last_name,locale,uid,gender,link,age_range,birthday'}
```

Pero al hacerlo no sé como obtener los parametros y los estoy pidiendo así:

```
name: auth['name']
a lo que antes llamaba así
name: auth['info']['name']
```

pero no funciona.

Comment: Te recomiendo que saques todo lo que puedas por la consola de tu servidor local para ver lo que recibes de Omniauth.
En tu controlador o en el servicio donde recibes la respuesta: `p auth`

Comment: ya vi los errores que daban!, la información extra a la basica se obtiene por ['extra']['raw_info']['parametro']

Comment: @DavidBazzingaJuggling te recomiendo publicar una respuesta para que otras personas puedan guiarse si se encuentran con un problema similar.

Answer (score 1):

Ya ha contestado el propio "preguntador".

Solo indicar que para Facebook los valores hay que buscarlos en extra/raw_info/[name] y por tanto habría que hacer algo así como:

```
# usuario.rb
class Usuario < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## otros métodos
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.name = auth.extra.raw_info.name if provider == "facebook"
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
  end
end
```

end

Más info sobre la respuesta completa de Facebook en https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook#auth-hash